# Pass multiple object arrays to C++ function from C#

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, interop, marshalling

I am trying to execute a c++ function (32 bit) from c# code (console application).

**C++ function signature:**

```
EngError GUIFN eUpdateRecord( 
                Order::X * odrX, //array of objects
                Order::Y * odrY, //array of objects
                Order::P * odrP,        //array of objects
                Order::Q * odrQ,        //single objects
                ulong A,
                ulong B,
                int & C)
```

where Order is the C++ namespace containing the below classes:

```
class X
{
    public:
        pb::Uint    XID;        //Uint is unsigned short
        pb::String  No;     //String is char *
        pb::String  Msg;        
};

class Y
{
    public:
        pb::Uint    YID;                    
        pb::String  Code;
        pb::Uint    OrderId;
        pb::String  Msg;    
        pb::Char    Status; 
        pb::Long    Capacity;
};
```

Classes P & Q are very similar to above classes with just change in property names (excluding them for now).

I am invoking the C++ function from C# as below

**C# Method**

```
[DllImport("x3iface.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]

public extern unsafe EngErr eUpdateRecord([In,Out] X[] odrX, [In, Out] Y[] odrY, [In, Out] P[] odrP, Q* odrQ, uint A, uint B, ref int C);
```

**Sample C# Class:**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
    public unsafe struct Y
    {
        public UInt16 YID;
        public char* Code;
        public UInt16 OrderId;
        public char* Msg;
        public byte Status;
        public Int32 Capacity;
    }
```

All arrays passed to the C++ function have pre-assigned values and the C++ function will update values of each array object based on some internal logic.

When i run the code and step into the C++ function, the values are mapped correctly for arrays X and Y, but i am getting the error 'Unable to read memory' for the array P and object Q. All the other values A,B and C are mapped correctly.
If i swap the position of inputs X and Y with P and Q in C++( the parameter positions are changed accordingly in C# method too), then P and Q starts working fine, but then i get the error 'Unable to read memory' for the arrays X and Y.

```
 public extern unsafe EngErr eUpdateRecord([In,Out] P[] odrX, Q* odrQ,[In, Out] X[] odrX, [In, Out] Y[] odrY,  uint A, uint B, ref int C);
```

Do we have any limitation in the number of [In,Out] object arrays we can marshal and pass to a C++ function? How can i best trouble shoot this error?
I do not have a provision to alter the functionality in C++ code as it is being reused in other applications. Kindly suggest possible solutions.